# How to service a Shimano TZ rear mech?

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, tourney

I'm trying to swap out the top jockey wheel on a rear shifter mechanism.

The bottom jockey wheel simply unbolted as expected but the top one seems to share a shaft with the main spring rather than having its own bolt.

I can twist one of the cage plates a complete turn but it doesn't unthread anything.

I can see a steel nubbin through a small slot, but its not shaped like a bolt head.

Is this Unserviceable?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why bother? A cheap new one is ~$40 but they're all direct mount now, not claws.  I have a 5 speed rear mech manaing to almost shift 7 gears and it doesn't quite sit on the end cogs.  This one was in my pile and seems to have the range required.  Plus I already have replacement jockey wheels from another project left over.

Comment: After semi-careful cleaning, drying, and lubricating, the original top jockey wheel is moving again, but its not even a tenth as good as the bottom replaced one.

Comment: Maybe the bolt is fixed with a C-clip through the slot? If true, you'd have hard time pulling it out. Probably because these are not intended for service. Also, TZ50 goes for a 15USD at Ali right now.

Comment: @Klaster_1 yeah replacement is a solution = I'm trying to avoid being a consumer.

Comment: I managed to make this work with my 34 tooth rear megarange cog by cutting off a metal tang that was getting caught on the wheel side of the cog where spring tension was not enough to move it back to the outboard side when changing down.  The jockey wheel still buzzes on the cog, but at least it changes without dismounting now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These units are simply not meant to be serviced. The end of the bolt looks stamped like a rivet anyhow.

It may be a bit short as an answer but it's the (bitter) reality.

Comment: Confirmed - its unserviceable.  But its on a beater bike and still works enough.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned my Shimano Tourney TZ today and i had the same problem (that's why i'm here). I cleaned the bottom wheel and it was clogged with dirt and hairs .I cleaned the top wheel the best i could because i can't remove it. It now moves good enough without having to struggle and breaking the derailleur.

This answer confirms that the top jockey wheel is not removable in another Tourney rear derailleur.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the top jockey wheel is simple.

Because the derailleur is budget the shaft for the top jockey wheel is riveted.

The photo also shows that there is a screwhead at the top. It will be necessary to remove this by first taking off the plastic cover, then cutting off the screw head.

This allows the shaft to be removed.

This shaft is then replaced with a standard bolt and nut on the outside, having serviced the jockey wheel.

There is rarely a component that is not serviceable. Manufacturers are relying on you not being able to work it out, or as in this case replace a riveted shaft with a standard bolt. A bolt cost a whole lot less than a replacement derailleur.

Comment: It's not as simple as that. The plastic cover seems to be held on by the riveted parallelogram bearings, so is not easily removable. The A pivot shaft likely cannot be replaced with an easily obtainable 'standard' bolt. The replacement would need to be long enough, threaded only at the end and the correct diameter for the internal bushings.